# Segmentation fault when trying to memset() a structure pointer to 0

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, structure

I just want to set 0 to a pointer to a structure like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct apple
{
     int f;
     int d;
     size_t tree;
};
struct apple *app;
int main(void)
{
 memset(&app,0,sizeof(app));
 app->tree = 1;
 app->d = 4;
 app->f = 2;
 printf("%d %d %lu\n",app->d, app->f, app->tree);
}
```

It compiles fine with `gcc -o foo foo.c` but when I run I get Segmentaion fault.
i tried `memset(app, 0 , sizeof(app));` but it complains, I tried `memset(*app, 0,sizeof(app));`also complains. This one compiles fine but I still get seg fault`memset((void *) &app, 0, sizeof(app));`

What should i do to set this pointer to struct **0**? If I have just a simple struct like **this**: `struct apple app;`*(without pointer)* it should go like `memset(&app, 0, sizeof(app));`

Because it's a pointer and memset has the first parameter a `void*` , why isn't working like passing just a simple variable without the **"&"** thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
memset(&app,0,sizeof(app));
```

Overwrites `app` (a pointer) with zeroes.  We're off to a bad start.

Then we try and reference `app` (which is now `NULL`):

```
app->tree = 1;
```

And things have gotten worse.

You want to *allocate* something for `app` to point to:

```
app = malloc(sizeof(struct apple));
memset(app, 0, sizeof(struct apple));
```

or

```
app = calloc(1, sizeof(struct apple));   // calloc zeroes things out for you
```

Comment: Ok I tried with malloc and with `memset(app, 0 , sizeof(*app));` and it works like a charm but without malloc it dosen't work .Why? Also please  explain me why  should  I use  my `sizeof(*app);` instead of `sizeof(app)`?

Comment: "without malloc it dosen't work why" Because using an uninitialized pointer is a dangerous, unpredictable, bad idea. `sizeof(app)` would just be the size of the pointer itself. This might be bigger, or smaller, than the size of the `struct`. Either you'll overwrite memory you don't own (bigger), or not fill the whole struct (smaller).

Comment: @Paul Roub: It's not overwriting some memory after it with zeroes, because the memset size is sizeof(app) (a pointer), not sizeof(*app) (a structure). So the memset is effectively equivalent to: `app = NULL;` (on all real world systems where a pointer of all zero bytes is the same as `NULL`). Obviously wrong, but it's not an overrun; memory before and after it remains unaffected, only the `NULL` dereference does bad things.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yup. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: One more correction: The malloc and calloc should be using `sizeof(*app)` for the allocation size, or it only allocates enough for the pointer, not the structure. When it works without that, it's a coincidence of malloc/calloc allocating at wider widths than requested (it might work, or it might corrupt your heap, have fun guessing which). :-)

Comment: Now after modification it works but i have another fast question. I'ts strange that when I try in my terminal  `valgrind ./foo` it says: `heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 16 bytes allocated` why 16 ? the size of my struct is 8 i think because sizeof(size_t) = 8bytes.

Comment: That's between you and your compiler; or at least, it's a separate question.

Comment: Maybe it should be noted that the `memset()` in the example is redundant - the pointer is already initialized to `0` since it is statically allocated.

Comment: @Hoenir: memory allocation routines typically round allocations to a block size that they work with.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `&app` as a parameter to `memset` here:

```
memset(&app,0,sizeof(app));
```

This means you're setting the value of that pointer to `0`. You then proceed to de-reference it.

```
app->tree = 1;
```

It is extremely unlikely that the address `0` points to a place you can write to (in fact, it is possible, but not given, that this address represent the null pointer.) This is enough to cause a segmentation violation.

You need to decide what you mean with "to set 0 to a pointer to a structure". If you want the contents of the pointee set to zero, then you can use `memset` thus, *after* making it point to some allocated memory:

```
app = malloc(sizeof(*app));  // allocate space for an apple object
memset(app, 0, sizeof(*app)); // app, not &app!!!
```

Note that you can allocate *and* zero initialize the allocated memory using [`calloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).

```
app = calloc(1, sizeof(*app));
```

If you really want to set the value of the pointer to 0, then perhaps you mean setting it to the null pointer, which you can achieve like this:

```
app = NULL;
```

But now you can't de-reference the pointer.

Comment: Note that even with things properly allocated, calling `memset(&app, ...)` is not doing what the OP intends.